# different result sets for 'unionall' and for 'union all'

Tags: sql

Why are we getting different result sets for 'unionall' and for 'union all'?

```
Select null
Union
Select null
Union all
Select null
```

#

```
Select null
Union
Select null
Unionall
Select null
```

Comment: You should probably check the documentation of whatever product you are using.

Comment: `unionall` would general an error in most databases.  Presumably that constitutes a "different" result.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, `UNIONALL` is not a valid operator / keyword in any SQL dialect.

If you run your examples in Microsoft SQL Server (for the sake of example) then the following results are returned:

Query 1 - a single result set as follows:

```
NULL
NULL
```

Query 2 - two result sets:

```
NULL
```

and

```
NULL
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a1cde2b7af1e376fd5d9c1c780c6142b

What is happening in the second query is that `Unionall` is being treated as a [column alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL)). Although you've written it on a separate line, that doesn't matter. If you'd written it as

```
Select null Unionall
```

the effect would be clearer. Running that line independently shows you that it names the column: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cd796a0f3a16156d56d2fe3d6d5f8459

Hence your second query is actually two *separate* queries, not a single unioned query. (The column naming doesn't appear in your version because you've unioned it with another `SELECT NULL` just above, and the column name of the first query in the union takes precedent.)